# [Vue warn]: Error in mounted hook: "TypeError: this.$refs.appConfirm.setCellphone is not a function"

Tags: vue.js, jestjs, vue-test-utils

I have an error trying to mock the refs in vue, since the solution I found uses stubs. But stubs only accept strings.

```js
it("Test component", () => {
  const wrapper = mount(NeedConfirmation, {
    localVue,
    store
  });
});
```

**[Vue warn]: Error in mounted hook: "TypeError: this.$refs.appConfirm.setCellphone is not a function"**

```js
it("Test component", () => {
  const appConfirm = {
    setCellphone: () => {}
  };
  const wrapper = mount(NeedConfirmation, {
    localVue,
    store,
    stubs: {
      appConfirm
    }
  });
});
```

**[vue-test-utils]: options.stub values must be passed a string or component**

Answer (score 1):

For a custom stubbed component, provide a component definition to `stubs`, e.g., from importing a `'*.vue'` file or defining a component object using the Vue Options API.

The following example defines the component inline in Vue 2 1️⃣, and verifies that `setCellphone` is called after mounting 2️⃣:

```js
import NeedConfirmation from '@/components/NeedConfirmation.vue'
import { mount } from '@vue/test-utils'

it('Test component', () => {
  const setCellphone = jest.fn()

  const wrapper = mount(NeedConfirmation, {
    stubs: {
      // 1️⃣
      appConfirm: {
        template: `<div></div>`,
        methods: {
          setCellphone
        }
      }
    }
  })

  // wait for refs to resolve in `mount()`...
  await wrapper.vm.$nextTick()

  // 2️⃣
  expect(setCellphone).toHaveBeenCalled()
})
```